# PHP: Remove multiple child tags

Tags: php, regex

```
<div class="article_content">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>

<ul>
 <li>UPDATE mytable SET tax = amount</li>
</ul>
<p>after you can remove it</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p> <!-- dot want to delete this line -->
<ul><li>ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN amount;</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to delete all `<p>&nbsp;</p>` until the first `ul` or any tag like `<p>.... content .... </p>` appears.

If I am going to use this one `str_replace("<p>&nbsp</p>","",$string);`, it will remove all empty lines from the string. But I want to delete lines until the first occurrence.

Comment: from where that data comes? from database?

Comment: yes..fetching from database. and store in database via ckeditor

Comment: that can be easily done with some client side scripts like `jquery` or `javascript`

Comment: you can consider `$dom = new DOMDocument();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you out, In removing all child nodes from starting which contains `&nbsp;` till the time a new tag appear with some content.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/783500)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$string= <<<HTML
<html><body><div class="article_content">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>

<ul>
 <li>UPDATE mytable SET tax = amount</li>
</ul>
<p>after you can remove it</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p> <!-- dot want to delete this line -->
<ul><li>ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN amount;</li>
</ul>
</div></body></html>
HTML;
$object = new DOMDocument();
$object->loadHTML($string);
$remove=array();
$nodelist=$object->getElementsByTagName("div")->item(0)->childNodes;
foreach($nodelist as $node)
{
    if($node instanceof DOMElement)
    {
        if($node->tagName=='p' && str_replace("&nbsp;","",htmlentities($node->textContent))=="")
        {
            $remove[]=$node;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
foreach($remove as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $object->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try jQuery instead of doing it in PHP, because jQuery is best library for DOM traversing and manipulation.

Try the below snippet, hope this will be better for you.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".article_content p").each(function() {
    var self = $(this),
      arr = []; // get all blank elements in array
    if (self.text().trim().length == 0 // check its length
      &&
      (self.prev().text().trim().length === 0 || // checking previous element is blank or not
        self.next().text().trim().length === 0)) { // checking next element is blank or not
      arr.push(self); // if all are blank then add in array
    }
    // now remove all elements
    $(arr).each(function() {
      $(this).remove()
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article_content">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <ul>
    <li>UPDATE mytable SET tax = amount</li>
  </ul>
  <p>after you can remove it</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!-- dot want to delete this line -->
  <ul>
    <li>ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN amount;</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: need to put this script what you have written in js inside ready function .so please edit and add ready function for the other people who will look up such kind of solution .

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've added it and updated my answer. You can add `jquery` tag in your question, so it is available in jquery questions.

Answer (score 0):

### This may be possible by client side language like jQuery

1. [.prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)  :- Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the previous sibling only if it matches that selector.
2. [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/)  :- Reduce the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

**Example shown below :-**

```js
$(function() {
var pTag = $( "ul" ).first().prevAll('p');
pTag.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article_content">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>

<ul>
 <li>UPDATE mytable SET tax = amount</li>
</ul>
<p>after you can remove it</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p> <!-- dot want to delete this line -->
<ul><li>ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN amount;</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Working but only for the one situatation it find ul tag but i want i did not dependent on any tag just remove if when found some `<p>&nbsp;</p>` till the first sentace occurrence

Answer (score 0):

**You can go this way also when inserting data in database.**
The default setting creates a paragraph element each time Enter is pressed: 
Change your CKEDITOR setting it is by default true.

```
config.autoParagraph = false;
```

and also you can set enter mode as BR and other relevant

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

[Read  this same question](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Empty-Paragraph-Tags-beginning-PageTable)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Press F11 to toggle full screen editting (Ctrl+⌘+F on Mac OS).
// Press Ctrl+Shift+F to format code.
$string = '
<div class="article_content">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>

<ul>
 <li>UPDATE mytable SET tax = amount</li>
</ul>
<p>after you can remove it</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p> <!-- dot want to delete this line -->
<ul><li>ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN amount;</li>
</ul>
</div>
';
$remove=array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
//$newstring = $dom->getElementsByTagName('<p>&nbsp;</p>')->item(4);
$newstring = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach($newstring as $stringnode)
{
        if($stringnode->tagName=='p' && str_replace("&nbsp;","",htmlentities($stringnode->textContent))=="")
        {
            $remove[]=$stringnode;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
}

foreach($remove as $node)
{

        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::removeChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in test.php:66 Stack trace: #0 /test.php(66): DOMNode->removeChild(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in test.php on line 66

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to use DOM while working with HTML structure. But in this specific case, unlike other answers, I prefer Regular Expressions more:

```
(?s)<(?:(?:ul|p>(?:(?!&nbsp;)|[^>]*</p>\s*(*ACCEPT)))).*\K
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/8IF1Lh/1)

### Regex explanation:

```
(?s)    # Enable DOTALL modifier
<       # Match a `<`
    (?:     # Start of non-capturing group (a)
        (?: # Start of NCG (b)
            ul  # Match `ul`
            |   # OR
            p>  # Match `p>`
            (?: # Start of NGC (c)
                (?!&nbsp;)   # Shouldn't be followed by `&nbsp;`
                |            # OR
                [^>]*</p>\s* # Otherwise match whole `p` tag
                (*ACCEPT)    # Force engine to end current matching attempt
            )   # End of NGC (c)
        )   # End of NGC (b)
    ).*\K   # End of NGC (a), match up to the end of input string and throw it away
```

PHP code:

```
echo preg_replace('~(?s)<(?:(?:ul|p>(?:(?!&nbsp;)|[^>]*</p>\s*(*ACCEPT)))).*\K~', '', $html);
```

[**PHP Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/ZouCe)